# Gnuplot output cropped when changing aspect ratio regardless of terminal type

Tags: gnuplot

Gnuplot doesn't usually provide me with such problems, but when I set the aspect ratio manually, or with 'set size square' the top part of the plot is cut/cropped off. Doesn't matter if term is aqua, jpeg, png, eps etc.

I'm on OSX and using 4.4 patch level 3 (Not the newest, as they have issues with terminal types).

Answer (score 1):

Most terminals allow you to set a size for the output -- e.g.:

```
set terminal png size 400,500  #size in pixels
set output "foo.png"
```

You can try playing around with the size of the output terminal to see if you can get it to work.  You can also use `set size` and `set origin` to make your plot a little smaller than it would normally be and to move it around on the "canvas" if needed.  Finally, if all else fails, you can set your margins explicitly:

```
set tmargin at screen 0.9  #top
set bmargin at screen 0.1  #bottom
set lmargin at screen 0.1  #left
set rmargin at screen 0.9  #right
```